# Mongoose findByIdAndUpdate doesn't generate _id on insert

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to use mongoose's `findByIdAndUpdate` method. When I am updating an existing document that has an **_id** fieldset, it works great. However, inserting a new doc, with `upsert: true` inserts one without `_id` generated (_id field is **null**) which leads to all sorts of issues. Why isn't upsert generating an `_id`?

Here is the code, for a new document `newRecord._id` is undefined:

```js
myModel.findByIdAndUpdate(newRecord._id, newRecord, {
  upsert: true, 
  new: true,
  runValidators: true,
  setDefaultsOnInsert: true
}, function(err, patient) {
  //do something 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are upserting, if you specify the first param, since it cant find NULL (mongoose treats undefined as null) it creates it.

I would say dont use findbyid and instead use model.update.